# How to download audio/video files from internet and store in iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, ios, download, audio-streaming, audio-player

I am developing an iPhone app for music. I want to give some options to the user so they can listen the **song/music by streaming** or they can **download the music in the app**. I know how to stream the audio files in the app programmatically. But, i don't know how to **download the audio files in the app and play** the audio after download. And also user can pause the download while it is in download. Is it possible to do ? Can anyone please guide me and please share any sample code or tutorial for me? I have one more doubt: Can you please help me to create a folder inside of the app? Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you should accept @Liam George Betsworth's answer,he did his best.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

**Creating a Folder**

For every app you have a `Documents Folder`. Any files you use in your app are stored here. If you want to create more directories here, then you'd do something like this:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; // Get documents folder
NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyNewFolder"];

if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dataPath])
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:dataPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error]; //Create folder if it doesn't already exist
```

**Downloading**

If you want to download audio files from the internet, then you want to look at an asynchronous method of doing it. This means that the application can carry on doing things while your download happens in the background.

For this, I recommend you use [ASIHTTPREQUEST](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/). It's great for carrying out any download requests, providing you with many options such as *pausing* a download (as you requested).

The website provides a great deal of documentation on downloading and storing a file. Take a look at the *Downloading a File* section on [this](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use) page.

You'd just do something like:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.fileurl.com/example.mp3"];
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setDownloadDestinationPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",dataPath]]; //use the path from earlier
[request setDelegate:self];
[request startAsynchronous];
```

Then just handle the progress and completion through the delegate methods that ASIHTTPRequest offers.

**Playing**

Playing the file is very simple. Once it's on the device and you know where it is, just load it into the audio player.

There's a great tutorial here on using [AVAudioPlayer](http://mobileorchard.com/easy-audio-playback-with-avaudioplayer/) to play sounds. A very simple example of using it in your case would be:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/audiofile.mp3",dataPath];

NSError *error;
audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];

if (audioPlayer == nil)
    NSLog([error description]);
else
    [audioPlayer play];
```

Comment: Great comment, well laid out explanation! +1

Comment: +1 for such a great answer :) ,this should be accepted, wondering why people ask question and disappear :(

Comment: I recommend using AFNetworking rather than ASIHTTPRequest, nevertheless what an excellent answer @LiamGeorgeBetsworth

Comment: I see lot of issues with ASHttpRequest,wonder why there is no simple way to download the images from server to documents directory. I have implemented downloading files from server,however trying to save to documents directory is not smooth,the files are getting saved in corrupt fashion. Please review my code [here](http://pastebin.com/EbR4kMdr) and kindly help me,thanks :)

Comment: And yes i agree with @GangstaGraham that he should use AFNetworking, but please look at the date. AFNetworking classes was not available back then.

Comment: @EshwarChaitanya Its better you use AFNetworking, because ASIHTTPRequest classes has a lot of bug which breaks the app very often. Almost everybody has switched to AFNetworking. I suggest you do it too, ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can download audio files and play downloaded files through AVAudioPlayer.  I don't exactly know how to pause when downloading, but I have downloaded audios and played. You can download either from ASIHTTP Request or other.

You can follow these links.

1. http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#tracking_progress
2. [About download file using ASIHttpRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3341658/about-download-file-using-asihttprequest)

Comment: Yes,Sure ASIHTTPRequest is best method, you should use this download your audio files, if problem came then please let me know, I will try to solve,insha Allah.