# playing downloaded audio video in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, avplayer

Hi seen many tutorial but couldn't find the right workable answer. I need to play audio and video file from my webservice, for this I want to download the file and play it in the app, seen tutorial for avPlayer nothing workable. Please provide link or guide how to do this.

Comment: what is te extension of the audio file?

Comment: are you trying to code a live streaming or the downloaded audio/video file

Comment: try this thread, it may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10245345/how-to-download-audio-video-files-from-internet-and-store-in-iphone-app

Answer (score 0):

Use MPMoviePlayer, as this can open network streams and despite the name works with audio. The only thing is this pops up the modal player with controls.

First Download the network file using NSURLConnection and store it locally, then use AVAudioPlayer to play the local file.