# Downloading File using AFHTTPRequest Operating isn't working?

Tags: objective-c, download, nsurlrequest

This is the code I'm using ([from this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10245345/how-to-download-audio-video-files-from-internet-and-store-in-iphone-app), although it's slightly modified):

```
NSLog(@"Saving File...");

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[detailDataSourceDict valueForKey:@"filepath"]]];
NSLog(@"This is the link you are downloading: %@",request);
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request] autorelease];

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *path = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
operation.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:path append:NO];

[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"Successfully downloaded file to %@", path);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];

[operation start];
```

I get the NSLog "Successfully downloaded file to /Users/xxxx/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.0/Applications/F29C1E99-A277-41DC-8205-6556B6123A85/Documents" but when I open up that folder in Finder, I don't see the file.  Is there anything that I am doing wrong?  I am not getting errors in my code.  Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

---

### Update

I am using the AFNetwork library...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting the download location to the actual Documents Directory, rather than a file in the directory. Update your code to use a specific file within the directory.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *path = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; //filepath to documents directory!
operation.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:[path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"filename.extension"] append:NO];
```

Also, I think you may want to be setting the `inputStream` property rather than the `outputStream` because you are downloading a file rather that uploading one.