# Ideal Way to Save Audio Data in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, core-data, audio, core-audio

I'm downloading and saving audio files from a URL. I'm trying to ensure that I'm properly implementing my variables and am storing the files themselves properly.

Is there an ideal or standard way of declaring variables to receive audio data or storing these downloaded files? I'm planning on just using `NSURLRequest` and `NSURLConnection` to download and save the files to the file system. Maybe reference them using CoreData. Is this a fairly standard way of going about this, or should I change my approach?

Comment: It depends on the server side as to whether or not it assigns correct MIME types to files that you download, I think.

Comment: @Sneagan Did it work for you?

Comment: Indeed it did. Thanks! Sorry for the delayed accept. Just moved!

Comment: Oh no problem! Just wanted to make sure if it works the same way for audio files or not. Thanks.

Comment: It does appear to work. If I encounter any issues later I'll definitely bring it up here. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe there is anything special that you need to do for downloading audio files. I have myself downloaded and saved video and PDF files before, both in the same and usual way and didn't have any issues.
 
For reference you can check this question out: [How to download audio/video files from internet and store in iPhone app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10245345/how-to-download-audio-video-files-from-internet-and-store-in-iphone-app) It has  a very nice detailed answer.
Hope this helps.